# Ionic google plus connect on browser platform

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm currently making a web app based on Ionic. I have a login page on which i'd like to integrate a google connect. I tried to install the ionic native Google Connect, but this one doesn't work on browser platform, only iOS and Android. I saw this plugin : https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-google-login
I tried to install it and i followed the instructions, here is the code :

```
import { AuthService, AppGlobals } from 'angular2-google-login';

constructor(private _googleAuth: AuthService){
}

 googleLogin() {
    this._googleAuth.authenticateUser(()=>{

    });
  }
```

The problem is on the node_modules directory. All the modules are in `.JS` format, but the angular2-google-signin directory has files in `.TS`. I have this error when i try to run on browser :

```
Error: ./~/angular2-google-login/index.ts Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Desktop/Myproject/node_modules/angular2-google-login/index.js'
```

I can't find any solution to put an Angular solution to sign in with Google on a browser platform.. 
Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score -1):

Not all plugins are meant to run on browser because some are dependent on device native features for e.g `SQLite database`, `camera` etc. You should test and run your app in mobile devices.

Comment: As said on my question, i'm making an app for the browser platform. 
As you recommend it, my app works on a mobile device, but I'd like to access to a Google signin on the browser platform, which should be possible (not like a camera which is accessible only on a mobile device)

Comment: Using native google login may not be an option for browser specific platform. You can use google login apis for that perpose

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-google-login
This is not a native plugin, this is a simple Angular plugin, not designed for Ionic

Comment: I tried to run the embedded demo its throwing error as well. May be better luck with another plugin